# Mirror command messing up UVs in 2.9

Tags: mesh, uv-image-editor, mirror

I just updated to 2.9 and am experiencing some strange behavior with the Mirror command and mesh UVs. Is this a bug or some weird setting I don't know is enabled?

Here is my setup:

[image: Default cube, mesh moved away from origin, UVs offset]

If I go into edit mode on the cube, Shift-D duplicate the mesh, mirror it across the X axis with the 3D cursor as the pivot, it at first seems OK but after exiting and entering edit mode again, the UVs of the mirrored portion of the mesh are messed up.

[image: Cube with mirrored duplicate showing the messed up UVs]

Any clue what's going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to a new feature, which attempts to correct face information (typically UV maps) when modifying the mesh.

In edit mode, look at the options top right of the 3D view and uncheck *"correct face attributes"*.

[image]

Intended or a bug in that case... maybe a bug.

Comment: Looks like this *would* fix the issue were it not for the bug mentioned in the other answer? Took a look and that option was already unchecked, still see the same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

"correct face attributes" is unchecked and it happend too.
think this is a bug. I already saw someone has posted it on blenders bug report:
https://developer.blender.org/T80623
Hope this get fixed soon.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** The problem with UVs and Vertex Colors is fixed in Blender 2.91.0 Alpha!

Vertex Colors get totally messed up too, see the picture.[image]