# After I merge by distance it automatically becomes marked sharp?

Tags: mesh

so I have two planes here. As you can see in this GIF I merge them together then select everything and use merge by distance. After I do that you can see it automatically marks it sharp around it. I do not want that to happen and it didn't happen in 2.83.

https://gyazo.com/0d5b27092304e75393bdc7568615938c

Comment: Is this 2.90 or 2.91?

Comment: This is in 2.90.

Comment: Could be around the same option as here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/193670/mirror-command-messing-up-uvs-in-2-9